# How to create a POSIX-compliant relative symbolic link in /bin/sh?

Tags: shell-script, shell, files, symlink, posix

The idea is to have the environment configured like this:

```
mkdir ~/shortcuts
cd shortcuts
ln -s ../.. up2
```

As a result I want to be able to go 2 directories up the file tree whenever I call:

```
~/dev/project/src$ CDPATH=~/shortcuts cd -P up2
~/dev$
```

I think I was able to achieve that on macOS a few weeks ago but I cannot remember how I did it (and now I'm not so sure about it any longer). Additionally, I'd like it to be portable (ideally, POSIX-compliant).

Comment: Alias `alias cd2up='cd ../..'`?

Comment: @myaut I'd prefer a solution based on a filesystem. I'm aware of the `alias` workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symlinks with relative paths as their contents are relative to the directory in which the symlink lives, not relative to the `cwd` of the process that resolves the symlink. The trick you are trying to achieve shouldn't be expected to work.

Comment: That's what I suspected after reading some SE threads and docs online.

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski, `alias up2='cd ../..'` is the clever way.  Otherwise, just use `cd ../..` or `cd ..` and `!!`; it's not *that* much typing.